# Multiple cross-compilation targets for drivers with CMake

Tags: c++, cmake, driver, firmware

I am developing a driver for a hardware module and I want to make it as portable as possible while using CMake. Are there best practices to achieve this?

There is common code that should be used in all platforms and platform-dependent code.
What directory structure fits this use case?
How do I structure the CMakeLists.txt files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would propose to have common implementation in the root your source directory while having dedicated architecture specifics in arch directory. Then you can select appropirate architecture dependent code in root `CMakeLists.txt` using

```
add_subdirectory( ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/arch/${CMAKE_TARGET_PROCESSOR} )
```

Samle project structure:

```
source/arch/arm/platform_dependent_code.cpp
source/arch/arm/CMakeLists.txt
source/arch/x86/platform_dependent_code.cpp
source/arch/x86/CMakeLists.txt
source/common_code.cpp
source/CMakeLists.txt <-- to contain add_subdirectory( ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/arch/${CMAKE_TARGET_PROCESSOR} )
```

Once `CMAKE_TARGET_PROCESSOR` CMake variable is set to `arm`, then only arm related code is built aside of common one, or once `x86` is set, `x86` and common code is used... the `add_subdirectory(...)` command does the magic for you

I am not sure how you handle the toolchains in multiple cross compilation but I would propose to use CMake toolchain files where `CMAKE_TARGET_PROCESSOR` shall be set... (see https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/-/wikis/doc/cmake/CrossCompiling)

Comment: Thanks, that does clear up the directory structure quite a lot. I came across ExternalProject_Add which would enable me to make a build per arch, providing the CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE directly, do you think that could work well?

Comment: I do not know, lacking experience with it. The solution I rougly described is the one I use in my project, I find it quite simple, easy to maintain. It also has the advantage you do not have to handle the arch management within source code,just in CMake. You just have to include the headers from arch, if you have the include path set up within the arch cmakelists.txt properly and having the same header names in all the platforms...

Comment: I tried your solution and it worked very nicely in combination with a top-level Makefile that can be used to set the Toolchain files for the different targets. Thank you very much for your solution.